# Disable SSL certificate checking for development

Tags: node.js, browser-sync

I've create a Browsersync proxy using `http-proxy-middleware` like this:

```
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var proxy = proxyMiddleware('/api', {
  target: 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api',
  changeOrigin: true   // for vhosted sites, changes host header to match to      target's host
});
```

When the server starts it creates the proxy:

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api
```

However because the development API uses a self signed cert it throws the following error when the API gets called.

```
[HPM] Proxy error: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT. undefined -> "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api"
```

Is there a way to disable this ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you should pass secure: false flag

```
   var proxy = proxyMiddleware('/api', {
         target: 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api',
         changeOrigin: true,
         secure: false 
    });
```